# How to set upper bound for x-axes for ploting using ggplot?

Tags: r

I'm using ggplot to create the plot of the density of my data.But I want to get plot for the X value until 2.0.
How can I put this restiriction in my code?

Here is my code and the plot:

```
ggplot()+geom_density(aes(data=Ge,x=GeN[,1]),color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: What are `Ge` and `GeN`?? This is not the way to use `ggplot`. If the first column of GeN has the x-values, and we assume the column is named X1, then use `ggplot(GeN) + geom_density(aes(x=X1),color="red")+xlim(0,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length)) + geom_density() + xlim(0, 2)
```

[image]